A version of Helly's theorem without convexity but connectivity
It's more than 100 years since Helly's celebrated theorem in discrete geometry was published by him, and yet ghosts still remain. The theorem in it's infinitary glory states

Let $\{X_j\}_{j\in J}$ be a collection of compact, convex sets in $R^d$ such that every subcollection of size at most $d+1$ have non-empty intersection, then the whole collection has non-empty intersection.

One can show that the compactness condition is necessary in some form. For example in $\mathbb R$, one can look at the family of intervals $I_n=[n,\infty)$. These are convex and any two of them have an intersection (they are nested), but the whole family has empty intersection. Although it is known that compactness can be weakened to all sets are closed and at least one of them is bounded.
People have generalised this to massive extents. One of them is via something called the $(p,q)$ property with respect to some set.

Definition : A family of sets $\mathcal F$ is said to satisfy the $(p,q)$ condition with resepct to a set $\mathcal T$ (called the transversal set) if for any $p\ge q$ sets from $\mathcal F$ (say $\mathcal F_p$), there exists $q$ sets in $\mathcal F_p$ that can be hit by a single set in $\mathcal T$ (hit by a set means has non-empty intersection with)

In this language, Helly's theorem reduces to saying that if a family of compact, convex sets in $\mathbb R^d$ has the $(d+1, d+1)$ property with respect to points, then the family can be hit by a single point.
What is interesting is looking at the transversal set to be hyperplanes. Alon and Kalai has shown the following.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a countable family of compact, convex sets in $\mathbb R^d$ satisfying $(p,q)$ property with respect to the set of all hyperplanes ($p\ge q\ge d+1$). Then there exists a constant $c$ (depending only on $p, q$ and $d$) such that $\mathcal F$ can be hit by at most $c$ many hyperplanes.

As a challenge, I wanted to see how far can the conditions be dropped. Compactness cannot be dropped (it has to be there in some form) as the family of open balls $B_n$ in $\mathbb R^2$ with center at $(n,1/n)$ and radius $1/n$ have the $(3,3)$ property with respect to lines, but cannot be hit by finitely many lines.
So I wanted to drop convexity and try adding just connectivity (and also work in $d\ge 2$ just so that the example is not too trivial). My gut feeling tells me the statement won't hold, but this is turning out to be very very hard for some reason.
So the question I really want to ask is whether there is a counterexample for this

Let $\mathcal F$ be a countable family of compact, connected sets in $\mathbb R^d$ ($d\ge 2$) satisfying $(p,d+1)$ property with respect to the set of all hyperplanes ($p\ge d+1$). Then there exists a constant $c$ (depending only on $p$ and $d$) such that $\mathcal F$ can be hit by at most $c$ many hyperplanes.


There is no counter-example to the proposition

Let $\mathcal F$ be a countable family of compact, connected sets in $\mathbb R^d$ ($d\ge 2$) satisfying $(p,q)$ property with respect to the set of all hyperplanes ($p\ge q \ge d+1$). Then there exists a constant $c$ (depending only on $p$, $q$ and $d$) such that $\mathcal F$ can be hit by at most $c$ many hyperplanes.

as it follows from the Alon--Kalai's result that you mentioned by replacing each element of $\mathcal{F}$ by its convex hull.
Let $\mathcal{F} = \{F_i\}_{i \in I}$ and for every $i \in I$, let $H_i$ be the convex hull of $F_i$. Then each $H_i$ is compact and convex. We write $\mathcal{H} = \{H_i\}_{i \in I}$.

The family $\mathcal{H}$ satisfies the $(p, q)$ property with respect to all hyperplanes, since $\mathcal{F}$ does. Indeed, for every subset $I_p \subset I$ of cardinality $p$, there exists a subset $I'_{q} \subset I_p$ of cardinality $q$ such that some hyperplane intersects all the elements in $\{F_i\}_{i \in I'_{q}}$. A fortiori, this hyperplane intersects all the elements in $\{H_i\}_{i \in I'_{q}}$.

Let $P$ be a hyperplane hitting every $H_i \in \mathcal{H}$. We claim that $P$ hits every $F_i \in \mathcal{F}$. Consider an arbitrary $i \in I$ and let $p \in P \cap H_i$. Thus $p$ can be written as a convex combination $p = \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j p_j$ where all $p_j \in F_i$. Let $L : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonconstant affine function whose kernel is $P$, so that $L(p) = 0$. Hence (relabelling the $p_j$s if necessary) we have $L(p_1) \le 0$ and $L(p_2) \ge 0$. If either inequality is an equality, then $L$ vanishes somewhere on $F_i$, meaning that $P \cap F_i \neq \varnothing$. So assume that both inequalities are strict. Since $F_i$ is connected and $L$ is continuous, the nonempty (relatively) open subsets $\{ L > 0\} \cap F_i$ and $\{ L < 0 \} \cap F_i$ do not cover $F_i$, hence there exists $p' \in F_i$ such that $L(p') = 0$, i.e., such that $p' \in P \cap F_i$. In every case, we see that $P$ hits $F_i$. Since $i \in I$ is arbitrary, $P$ hits $\mathcal{F}$.

By Alon--Kalai's result, there exists a constant $c$ (depending only on $p$, $q$ and $d$) such that $\mathcal{H}$ can be hit by at most $c$ hyperplanes. From the previous bullet, it follows that $\mathcal{F}$ can be hit by the same hyperplanes (and only by those).


